# Winter 19 Custom Labels

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customlabel

Since Winter 19 is applied in our scratch org, we have the following message on ALL our custom labels directly referenced from custom lightning components.

Example:

```
{!$Label.c.Persons}
```

> $LABEL.C.PERSONS COULD NOT BE RETRIEVED FROM CUSTOM LABELS: THIS RECORD COULD NOT BE LOADED BECAUSE IT INCLUDES TOO MANY FORMULA FIELDS
>   WITH COMPLEX FORMULAS, OR TOO MANY CUSTOM FIELDS. ASK YOUR SALESFORCE
>   ADMINISTRATOR TO REMOVE SOME FORMULA FIELDS OR SIMPLIFY THE FORMULAS
>   IN USE

The message has no sense ... We do not use formulas (complex or not), and .. custom labels are not records, they are custom labels ...

Anyone has this issues and maybe has found some workaround, even if I fear that the solution is a fix of SFDC platform?

Comment: You have a namespace? are you able to access these in Apex? is Transalation workbench enabled in your scracth org?

Comment: We don't have namespaces in this org. We are able to access them in apex. Translation workbench is activated

Comment: Case is 20052607 , if someone from salesforce needs access :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue in our org since it was upgraded to Winter '19.
In our case we had a Lightning Component which used hundreds of custom labels and caused all the Lightning components in the same page to display the error reported in your question.

EDIT

If you had the same problem this was fixed by SalesForce today.